# Are the attacks of a Wild Shaped druid considered weapon attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, wild-shape, natural-weapon

### Context

My character is a druid 3 / ranger 2. I'm considering taking *[Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)* as one of my ranger spells, but I'm not sure whether it would trigger while attacking in Wild Shape. The spell says:

> You choose a creature you can see within range and mystically mark it as your quarry. Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack. [...]

So my question is: do the attacks in Wild Shape count as weapon attacks?

### Related

- [Is a Wild Shape attack considered an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50654/is-a-wild-shape-attack-considered-an-unarmed-strike)
- [Are the beast shape weapon attacks of a Druid, simple or finesse?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79542/are-the-beast-shape-weapon-attacks-of-a-druid-simple-or-finesse)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Yes

When you are transformed you are using the stat block of the beast you are transformed into. The attacks a beast makes are melee weapon attacks. Using an example from the humble badger:

> ***Bite.** Melee Weapon Attack:* [...]

Generally any attack that is not a spell attack is a weapon attack. Do note that weapon attacks are not necessarily attacks with a weapon, which is relevant for certain spells and effects.

Comment: +1 One might add that teeth, claws, etc. are often considered as natural weapons. This makes it more plausible that Bite counts as a weapon attack.

Comment: Re "*Generally any attack that is not a spell attack is a weapon attack.*", Exceptions: Grappling and shoving are non-weapon melee attacks. (And the rolls involved in grappling and shoving aren't attack rolls. And successful grapple or shove isn't considered a hit.)

Comment: @ikegami Precisely, and hence the "generally"