# Can I move Hunter's Mark to a new target while in Wild Shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, druid, ranger, wild-shape

Following up on:

- [Are the attacks of a Wild Shaped druid considered weapon attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167299/are-the-attacks-of-a-wild-shaped-druid-considered-weapon-attacks), and
- [Can you move the Hunter's Mark spell on the same turn that the affected creature dies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159580/can-you-move-the-hunters-mark-spell-on-the-same-turn-that-the-affected-creature)

### Context

My druid/ranger has *[Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark)* active on target one. Target one dies while I'm wildshaped in, let's say, a dire wolf. On my next turn I want to move the mark to target two. Can I do that while still being a beast?

The spell mentions:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Yes, you can move a Hunter's Mark while in Wild Shape.

That is, as long as you still have a Bonus Action left in that turn, and your character still holds their concentration on the spell. [Hunter's Mark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunters-mark) indeed mentions:

> If the target drops to 0 hit points before this spell ends, you can use a bonus action on a subsequent turn of yours to mark a new creature.

**Wild Shape** says:

> You can't cast spells, and your ability to speak or take any action that requires hands is limited to the capabilities of your beast form.

So you can't cast *new* spells, but on spells your character is already concentrating the rules continue:

> Transforming doesn't break your Concentration on a spell you've already cast, however, **or prevent you from taking actions that are part of a spell, such as Call Lightning, that you've already cast.**

According to this highlighted rule, being a beast doesn't stop a druid/ranger from moving a mark, since Hunter's Mark was already active and the spell doesn't mention requiring hands to move it to a new target.

---

Let's also take a closer look at the example of *[Call Lightning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/call-lightning)*:

> On each of your turns until the spell ends, you can use your action to call down lightning in this way again, targeting the same point or a different one.

The wording of Call Lightning and Hunter's Mark are similar enough to conclude that yes, you can move a Hunter's Mark while in Wild Shape.