# Can a monk/druid use Flurry of Blows while in wild shape?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, monk, multi-classing

In D&D 5e, can a monk/druid use the monk ability Flurry of Blows in wild shape?

Comment: @Miniman I think there's an argument that this isn't a duplicate.  That question asks about unarmed attacks in general, this one asks if you can use Flurry of Blows.  It's a different case because Flurry of Blows is a class feature, whereas unarmed attacks are generic and can be made by any character.

Comment: This depends on OP, if he can ellaborate more that this isn't a duplicate, I'd vote to reopen

Comment: @LegendaryDude Fair point - I guess I just assumed that the question was asking about the more complex issue.

Comment: @daze413 Not sure what there is to elaborate on.  It seems pretty straight forward to me.  It may not be a great question, but it certainly can be answered as is.  The linked question is asking about a different issue (unarmed attacks).

Comment: @LegendaryDude Well, we are presuming here that OP knows he can use the feature because it is (sort of) clear in the Wild Shape rules. OP needs to elaborate if he is asking (a) Can a Druid/Monk perform Unarmed Strikes? [in this case, rightfulyl closed as duplicate] or (b) [Is a Wild Shape attack considered an unarmed strike?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50654/23064) [which is still a duplicate] or (c) another question entirely. Both a and b ask about if Flurry Blows can trigger, he knows he _can_ use the Flurry, just not if he can. Oh boy, I;m even confusing myself

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When using *Wild Shape*, you still have access to any features granted from your class, race, feats, and so on. (PHB, pg 67)

Comment: I think it's worth referencing the "as long as the new form is physically capable" clause. A druid/monk wildshaped into a python isn't issuing a flurry of blows, for instance....

Comment: @nitsua60 True, but I think *that* falls under "can I make an unarmed attack?" in the linked duplicate.  If you're a snake, can you make an unarmed attack with your tail?  You still have a head, so can you headbutt?  I imagine a big enough anaconda would have enough force behind a headbutt/whip to do at least *some* damage.